# adjust boxes in HTML- Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, as of right now, there are 3 boxes of span2 and height 140px, and 1 box of span6 and height 400px.

Since there is so much space left below the 3 small boxes, I want to add 3 more boxes of same span and same height.

Here is my **code.**

```
<div class="row-fluid"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
     <div class="span2 ">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="height:140px">
              <p></p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="span2">
         <div class="thumbnail" style="height:140px">
              <p></p>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="span2">
         <div class="thumbnail" style="height:140px">
              <p></p>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="span6">
         <div class="thumbnail" style="height:400px">
             <div id="pie_graph"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the snapshot.[image: I want to utilize the vacant position over here.]

I want to utilize the vacant position over here.

I tried making another div of `row-fluid` and then 3 boxes of span2 but they come below the above div, leaving the area vacant.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the span2's in a span6. Add 2 fluid rows and rename the span2 to span4 (fluid-rows are relative)

Here is an example: http://bootply.com/98914